# APK Analyzer not opening by any method in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, apk, apkanalyzer

I have tried every way to Open the APK analyzer for my flutter app in the Android Studio but it just doesn't open, I have tried the following methods found on developer.android.com:

- Drag an APK or app bundle into the Editor window of Android Studio.
- Switch to the Project view in the Project window, then double-click the APK in the default
  build/output/apks/ directory.
- Select Build > Analyze APK in the menu bar, then select your APK or app bundle.

Please help me open the apk analyzer as I have to use it to compare and reduce the size of a generated apk file.

Android studio version is: 2023.1.1.27

Comment: no, I want to use the APK analyzer for specific reasons, kindly guide me on that

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. In my case I had a Flutter project open and the analyzer would not open. Closing the Flutter project and opening a normal Android project the analyzer opened my APK.

Comment: Still didn't solve my problem